# Error on saving user input to an array perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I keep getting error in my perl script when using strict with array variables.

```
   #!/bin/perl

   use strict;
   use warnings;

   print "Enter Attributes for query: "
   my @ak = split(/\s+/, <>);
   foreach (@ak) {
       printf "%s\n", $_;
   }
   exit;
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Global symbol "@ak" requires explicit package name at ./test2.pl line 7.
Global symbol "@ak" requires explicit package name at ./test2.pl line 8.
Execution of ./test2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I used the page [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/perl-stdin-to-array-881748/) as an example as to get user input.

What is wrong with my array declaration?

---

I found out that the script works without error if I declare the array at the top like: `my @ak;` and remove the `my` from the subsequent use of `@ak`.

Comment: `;` is not optional as a statement separator.

Comment: But the script worked when I declared the array initially @Mat. I did not change anything else. Just declared the variable initially and removed `my` from the line following print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how you've declared `@ak`.  The problem is you're missing a semi-colon on line 6 just before the declaration.

Perl fails to recognize `my @ak` because it was in the middle of parsing the print statement.  This has confused the compiler and it doesn't give you a more useful error message.  In general, it's useful to look just before a syntax error in addition to the line the error is on.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Will be careful and check the preceding line from now on.